# Enviar XML por SoapClient en vez de curl

Tags: php, xml, soap

Estoy creando una petición por SOAP y no consigo que funcione con la forma [soapClient](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php) de PHP
solo lo he consegido mandando directamente el xml por Curl

Este el xml que me gustaría mandar por soapClient

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:elem='http://ftth.xxxxxx.com/elementoscomunes' xmlns:res='http://ftth.xxxxxxx/ReservaElementos'>
   <soapenv:Header>
      <elem:CABECERA>
         <Element>
            <Key>OPERADOR</Key>
            <Value>xxxxx</Value>
         </Element>
      </elem:CABECERA>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <res:ENTRADA>
         <ID_DOMICILIO> xxxxxx</ID_DOMICILIO>
         <TEMPLATE>xxxxxxx</TEMPLATE>
         <REMOTE_ID>xxxx</REMOTE_ID>
         <PPAI/>
   <TV_REMOTE_ID>xxxxxxxxx</TV_REMOTE_ID>         
      </res:ENTRADA>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Esta es la forma que me ha funcionado por curl

```php
$endpoint  = 'https://xxxxx/ftth_ufinet/reserva';
$curl = curl_init($endpoint);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // SSL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // SSL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
```

y aqui intento replicarlo con soapClient

```php
$opt_01 = array(
    'location'       => $endpoint,
    'keep_alive'     => true,
    'trace'          => true,
    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => $context
);

$params = [
    'ID_DOMICILIO' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'TEMPLATE' => 'xxxxxx',
    'REMOTE_ID' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'PPAI' => '',
    'TV_REMOTE_ID' => 'xxxxxxxx',
];

$header_part = '
    <elem:CABECERA>
        <Element>
            <Key>OPERADOR</Key>
            <Value>602</Value>
        </Element>
    </elem:CABECERA>
';

$soap_var_header = new SoapVar( $header_part, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null );
$soap_header = new SoapHeader( 'http://ftth.xxxxxx.com/elementoscomunes', 'wse', $soap_var_header );

try {
    $client = new SoapClient(endpoint?wsdl, $opt_01);
    print("<pre>".print_r($client->__getFunctions(),true)."</pre>"); // de esta manera saco los metodos del wsdl
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $return = $client->Reserva_Recursos($params);
    print("<pre>".print_r($return, true)."</pre>");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print("<pre>".print_r(get_object_vars($e),true)."</pre>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he conseguido trabajar con SoapClient, el problema me venia que no construia bien el header
forzando que el namespace fuera `elem`, lo he arreglado dejando que php gestione los nombres del namespaces que al final da lo mismo como lo llames.

```php
$endpoint  = 'https://xxxxx/ftth_ufinet/reserva';

$opt_01 = array(
    'location'       => $endpoint,
    'keep_alive'     => true,
    'trace'          => true,
    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => $context
);

$params = [
    'ID_DOMICILIO' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'TEMPLATE' => 'xxxxxx',
    'REMOTE_ID' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'PPAI' => '',
    'TV_REMOTE_ID' => 'xxxxxxxx',
];

$headerbody = array(
    'Element'=> ['Key'  => 'OPERADOR' ,'Value' => 'xxxx']
); 
$header = new SoapHeader('http://ftth.xxxxxxx.com/elementoscomunes', 'CABECERA', $headerbody);     

try {
    $client = new SoapClient("$endpoint?wsdl", $opt_01);
    print("<pre>".print_r($client->__getFunctions(),true)."</pre>"); // de esta manera saco los metodos del wsdl
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $return = $client->Reserva_Recursos($params);
    print("<pre>".print_r($return, true)."</pre>");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print("<pre>".print_r(get_object_vars($e),true)."</pre>");
}

// con esto podemos ver la petición enviada
print("<pre>".print_r($client->__getLastRequest(), true)."</pre>");
```

**REQUEST** resultante

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://ftth.xxxxxxxx.com/ReservaElementos" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://ftth.xxxxxxxx.com/elementoscomunes">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:CABECERA>
            <Element>
                <Key>OPERADOR</Key>
                <Value>xxxxx</Value>
            </Element>
        </ns2:CABECERA>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ENTRADA>
            <ID_DOMICILIO>xxxxxxxxxxxx</ID_DOMICILIO>
            <TEMPLATE>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</TEMPLATE>
            <REMOTE_ID>xxxxxxxxxx</REMOTE_ID>
            <PPAI></PPAI>
            <TV_REMOTE_ID>xxxxxxx</TV_REMOTE_ID>
        </ns1:ENTRADA>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```